# how to set the image to its orignal state after pinch and rotate gesture ends?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have added rotate and pinch gesture simountansly but after gesture end i want my image to come in its original state .

here is a code of my function handling rotation gesture

```
-(void)handlerotation:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)roatategesture
{
   if(roatategesture.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
   {
    roatategesture.rotation = 0.0;
    return;
   }
   self.myimage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.myimage.transform, roatategesture.rotation);
   roatategesture.rotation=0.0;
}
```

Comment: are your gesture applied in UIImageView right?

Comment: i have collection view and on clicking that cell in collection view new view open having that image and on that i have applied the gesture yeah on that secondd view controller i have a UIImageView element

Comment: trying to store first transform of uiimageview and than pinch and rotate image and after you done than re assign stored transform to UIImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
if(roatategesture.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    roatategesture.rotation = 0.0;
    self.myimage.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    return;
}
```